# Distinct Digit Year -Codewars Challenge-

Tags: javascript, object, while-loop

I was solving a codewars challenge and got stuck in an endless loop. The task is to find from a given input like year 1987 the next greater integer that has only distinct digits. In that case it would be 2013 as 1988, 1998,2000 etc. do not have 4 distinct digits. I wanted to solve this task with an Object and see where the length of the `Object.keys(obj)` is equal to 4.

Here is my try

```js
function distinctDigitYear(year) {
  
  let obj = {}
  let count = 1
  let yearCounter = year + count
  
  while (Object.keys(obj).length !==4) {
    obj = {}
    yearCounter.toString().split('').forEach(el=> {
      if(!Object.keys(obj).includes(el)){
        obj[el] = 1
      } else {
        obj[el] +=1
      }
    }
    )
   
      count++
  }
  return yearCounter + 1
}

distinctDigitYear(2000)
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What's your question, exactly? [ask]

Comment: So you're asking us to solve the codewars challenge and you submit it as your work?

Comment: You never update `yearCounter` within the loop.

Comment: Try to use console.log(someValue) to check that variables actually contain what you expect them to

Comment: @Pellay I see it more as "my code infinite loops, why is that"

Comment: `if(!Object.keys(obj).includes(el)){` can be written as `if (!obj[el]) {`, it won't affect the infinite loop but it's shorter and more efficient.

Comment: @James I agree, my statement was too abrupt. I'd also like to suggest opening the console adding a break point and stepping through the function. It really helps with seeing what values are where and how the function is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Details are commented in eample below***

```js
// Pass a 4 digit year -- 1987
function distinctDigitYear(year) {
  ++year; // Increment -- 1988
  /*
  Convert year number into a String. Spread the String into 4 
  separate characters with the spread operator ... then convert an 
  Array into a Set eliminates any duplicates, then convert it back to an Array.
  */
  let yyyy = [...new Set([...year.toString()])];
  // If there are no dupes, yyyy will be 4 characters
  if (yyyy.length === 4) {
    /*
    join() the array into a String and return it
    */
    return yyyy.join('');
  }
  /*
  If the lenght of yyyy is less than 4
  recursively call dDY() passing next year through.
  */
  return distinctDigitYear(year);
};

console.log(distinctDigitYear(1987));
console.log(distinctDigitYear(2020));
console.log(distinctDigitYear(1910));
```